# Kotlin InstantiationException

Tags: android, kotlin, instantiationexception

This is one of my first Kotlin projects and I'm following the Codelabs from android to get up to speed with Kotlin. Android development is not new to me but googling for solutions to problems I'm finding more tutorials and solutions in Kotlin than Java. Its time to start moving to that language since Android has moved to "Kotlin first".

I'm not familiar var/val and how I can set onClick() listeners. While playing with this project I have tried quite a few things and decided to go back to using the android:onClick in XML so I don't have to make global variables in the Activity.

It started crashing on me for `java.lang.InstantiationException`

I commented out all code in the Activity and removed the android:onClick in the xml. Im still getting the same error. After rebuilding and cleaning the project, I tried `Invalidate Cache / Restart` that didn't help either.

I'm sure I can just create a new project and re-implement the code where I left off but I can't do that with larger projects. I don't know what caused this to throw this error and why it won't go away no matter what I try.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="2"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRoll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Roll"

            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/roll" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCountUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="Count Up"

            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnRoll" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.kotlinhelloword

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView

abstract class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
//    private var rollVal: TextView = findViewById(R.id.roll)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun rollDice(view: View) {
//        rollVal.text = (1..6).random().toString()
    }

    fun countUp(view: View) {
//        val current = rollVal.text.toString().toInt()
//
//        if (current < 6) {
//            rollVal.text = (current + 1).toString()
//        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.kotlinhelloword">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kotlinhelloword, PID: 19539
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kotlinhelloword/com.example.kotlinhelloword.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.kotlinhelloword.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.kotlinhelloword.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:41)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: It's because you've marked your `MainActivity` class as `abstract`. See the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#abstract-classes) for more info.

Comment: Just remove **abstract** and use like `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()`

Comment: gotta love IDE refactoring... thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

Instead of

```
abstract class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

Comment: I lost 2 hours try to finding solution.. thanks bro